# How to get the SSH connection running on Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.6

I would like to use the SSH feature that comes with the Eclipse Helios but I haven't found a good step by step tutorial on this. The Help that comes with Eclipse Helios is not that helpful since it had sections of information on the SSH that are not really what I call a step by step type of help.

The furthest I got with the setting is:
File-->New-->Other-->Remote System Explorer -->Connection --> SSH Only-->(Host Name: 192.169.1.200; Connection name: My connection; Description: My Description)--->SFTP Files(ssh.files; ssh.shells; ssh.terminal).

Not sure what I supposed to do with ssh.files; ssh.shells; ssh.terminal and if there is something else I have to setup. Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. To recap you follow this:

```
File-->New-->Other-->Remote System Explorer -->Connection --> SSH Only-->
(Host Name: 192.169.1.200; Connection name: My connection; Description: 
My Description)--->SFTP Files(ssh.files; ssh.shells; ssh.terminal)-->Finish
```

Then

```
go to: Window-->Open Perspective-->Other-->Remote System Explorer.
```

On the left side a window called Remote Systems will show your connections. Click on the connection you just created and it will ask you for the login info - Done. Now you can edit the remote files straight from your Eclipse.